# Categories field on Custom Labels

Tags: administration, translation, customlabel, translation-workbench

Is the Categories field on Custom Labels merely for use in List View filters? Can I not download a file of Custom Labels and their translations, filtering on Categories? Even the Translation Workbench Export file does not contain the Categories field.

Comment: I'd file this in Salesforce Ideas!